# Loop with printf in NASM

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, x86, nasm

In the first loop I fill the `array`, then I want to print this array, but I'll have an error. It's `Segmentation fault`. I just change `ecx` register, since is my counter for `_loop2`.

```
extern  printf

SECTION .bss
    array resb 10

SECTION .data
    fmt: db "array[%d] = %d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0'


SECTION .text

global main

main:
    mov ecx, 0

_loop:
    inc ecx
    mov [array + ecx * 4], ecx
    cmp ecx, 10
    jnz _loop

    mov ecx, 0


_loop2:
    jmp print
    add ecx, 1
    cmp ecx, 10
    jnz _loop2
    
    ret

print:
    ;push    ebp        ; set up stack frame
    ;mov     ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    push    dword [array + ecx * 4] ; value of variable a SECOND
    push    dword fmt   ; address of ctrl string
    call    printf      ; Call C function
    
    add     esp, 8      ; stack (4 * 2)

    ;mov     esp, ebp   ; takedown stack frame
    ;pop     ebp        ; same as "leave" op

    mov     eax,0       ;  normal, no error, return value

    ;ret            ; return
```

Comment: You have 10 bytes of space in `array`, but you're storing 10 dwords there (= 40 bytes).  That's not good.

Comment: Also, the `_loop2` loop never actually runs, because you unconditionally jump over it.  Have you tried single-stepping this code with a debugger?  That's a critically important practice for assembly programming, and when you do it I think you'll better understand what you have written.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, I should change size of ```resb```?

Comment: Better, change it to `resd 10` so that it counts how many dwords to reserve space for.

Comment: Also also, you push `ecx` before the call to `printf` but you never pop it off again, so if you try to return, you will return to the address pushed, which is 0.  But you have the `ret` commented out, so the function will not even try to return but will go on executing whatever garbage happens to be next in memory.

Comment: It looks like you're intending `print` to be a subroutine, in which case you need to call it with `call` instead of `jmp`, and you need to put the `ret` back in.  And fix the `ecx` issue as mentioned.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, I open this program in IDA and have problem with ```_loop2```, since it's infinite loop. Then I changed ```jmp``` to ```call```, but my ```ecx``` register is equal zero always. Where I should add the ```pop``` instruction?

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues as mentioned in comments:

- `array resb 10` will reserve space for 10 bytes, but you want to store 10 dwords there (40 bytes).  Change to `array resd 10`.
- (Pointed out by Sep Roland) In `_loop` you have an off-by-one bug; since the `inc` is done before the `mov` you will access the dwords at `[array+4], [array+8], ... [array+40]`, where the last one is out of range.  This is like doing `int array[10]; for (i=1; i <= 10; i++) array[i]=i;` in C, and is incorrect for exactly the same reason.  One fix would be to do `mov [array + ecx * 4 - 4], ecx` instead.
- After `_loop2` you have `jmp print`, which will transfer control to `print` and never come back.  Since you apparently want to call `print` as a subroutine and continue executing with `add ecx, 1 ; cmp ecx, 10`, etc, you need to `call print` instead of `jmp`.  And also uncomment the `ret` at the end of `print` so that it will actually return.  Subroutines in assembly language don't automatically return unless you actually execute `ret`; otherwise the CPU will just continue executing whatever garbage happens to be next in memory.
- You have a `push ecx` to save the value of `ecx` before the call to `printf`, which is good since `printf` will overwrite that register, but you need to `pop ecx` afterwards to get that value back and put the stack back to where it was.

  Specifically, the `pop ecx` should follow the `add esp, 8`; a stack is a last-in-first-out structure, and the `push ecx` was before the pushing of the `printf` arguments, so you need to `pop ecx` after removing those arguments from the stack.
- The `mov eax, 0` as a return value at the end of `print` is unnecessary since you never use it anywhere else.

With these changes the code works as it should.

Comment: There's one more error that you could add to your answer. The loop that fills the array has a buffer overflow! The first write goes to the second element and **the tenth write goes past the storage**. It's easily resolved using `mov [array - 4 + ecx * 4], ecx`. This will create an array filled with numbers 1 to 10.

Comment: True.  I added your suggestion to the answer.